# Using Django How Can I Automatically Update Information on a Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm not looking for exact code, but rather some guidance on my problem. On one of my pages, I want to have a small section that will tell the user the disk space left on the server and I want this information to update every 30 seconds. I have the code already written to get the disk information. However, I am unsure on how to display that information and have it update. This is what I have, just to give you a visual:

The HTML I'm working with: 
    {% extends "Checklist/base.html" %}

```
{% block main_content %}

  <form action="{% url 'Checklist:run' %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Run">
  </form>

  <label for="disk_space">Disk Space: </label>
    <input type="text" name="disk_space" value="{{ disk_space }}" id="disk_space">


{% endblock %}
```

The Views Function for the HTML:

```
def submit(request): #start scrtipt
    submit.preProcess = subprocess.Popen(['chmod', '+x /home/psvuser/Desktop/test.sh'])
    submit.process = subprocess.Popen(['/home/psvuser/Desktop/test.sh'])

    global sem
    sem = True
    disk_space = request.get('disk_space', '')
    disk_space = diskSpace()

    start_time= int(round(time.time()))
    f = open("/home/psvuser/Desktop/writer.txt", "a")
    f.write(str(start_time))
    f.write(", ")

    return render(request, 'Checklist/stop.html')
```

I have an idea on how to periodically refresh the page, however, I don't know how to display 'disk_space' onto the html.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to do regular asynch calls to your server while a page is already loaded, I would use AJAX to solve this problem.

I'd usually do something like this

```
def your_django_view(request):
    # magic 
    server_data = '98% left!' 
    response_data['data'] = server_data
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Then in your view, use some jquery (or javascript..whatever) to deal with all of the data

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
         url: '/function_url/',
         data: {
           },
          success: function(response_data) {
              var server_mem = response_data['data']
             $('#disk_space').val(server_mem);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this return statement at the end of your `submit` view:

```
return render_to_response('Checklist/stop.html',
    {'disk_space':disk_space},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The second argument of [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) is a dictionary of `{'key':value, 'key2':value2}` you can use in the template.